# Extract Values from Radiobutton

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button

I am attempting to use Radiobuttons to allow a user to select one of three options.  However, I cannot seem to get the value from the user's selection.  I'm very new to python and my strategy here may be completely incorrect.  Is the two-program approach correct here? Thank you for any advice you can offer!

```
def GetGroup():
    groupselect=tk.Tk()

    #select group
    group=IntVar()
    group.set(0)
    print(group)

    Label(groupselect,text="Select Group").grid(row=0,column=1)
    Radiobutton(groupselect,text="Group 1",width=20,variable=group,value=1,state=NORMAL).grid(row=1,column=1)
    Radiobutton(groupselect,text="Group 2",width=20,variable=group,value=2,state=NORMAL).grid(row=2,column=1)
    Radiobutton(groupselect,text="Group 3",width=20,variable=group,value=3,state=NORMAL).grid(row=3,column=1)

    group=group.get()

    Button(groupselect,text="Submit",width=20,command=lambda:GetGroup2(group)).grid(row=4,column=1)


def GetGroup2(group):

    if group==1:
        ma_group="group1"
    if group==2:
        ma_group="group2"
    if group==3:
        ma_group="group3"
    if group==0:
        ma_group="group did not update"

    print(ma_group)
```

Comment: Incorrect indensts - change it.

Comment: Did you run it in console/terminal to see error message ? Did you get error message (trackback) ? Show it - all text - with nuber of line with problem.

Comment: There isn't an error message, but when I run the code "ma_group" prints the value "group did not update", so the "group" variable is not being changed by the radiobuttons...

Answer (score 0):

Don't overwrite some variables in Tkinter

```
group=group.get()
```

because Tkinter sometimes assign variable in widgets not at once but later when it will need it - it is called `"lazy evaluation"`

Because `group` is in the same function with `Radiobutton` so `Radiobutton` (as `variable`) will use new `group` - not oryginal reference to `IntVar`

Working example:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

groupselect=tk.Tk()

#select group
group=IntVar()
group.set(0)
print(group)

Label(groupselect,text="Select Group").grid(row=0,column=1)
Radiobutton(groupselect,text="Group 1",width=20,variable=group,value=1,state=NORMAL).grid(row=1,column=1)
Radiobutton(groupselect,text="Group 2",width=20,variable=group,value=2,state=NORMAL).grid(row=2,column=1)
Radiobutton(groupselect,text="Group 3",width=20,variable=group,value=3,state=NORMAL).grid(row=3,column=1)

####group=group.get()

Button(groupselect,text="Submit",width=20,command=lambda:GetGroup2(group)).grid(row=4,column=1)


def GetGroup2(group):
    group = group.get() # group as local variable in `GetGroup2`
    if group==1:
        ma_group="group1"
    if group==2:
        ma_group="group2"
    if group==3:
        ma_group="group3"
    if group==0:
        ma_group="group did not update"

    print(ma_group)
```

Comment: It is still not working, it keeps printing "group did not update". I tried creating a different variable in GetGroup2 called num, so that `num=group.get()`  but that did not solve it either.

Comment: problem is line `group=group.get()` in `GetGroup()` not in `GetGroup2()`

Comment: I pasted your example in and it didn't work. `group = group.get()` is now in `GetGroup2()` instead of `GetGroup()`.  Was there something else I needed to adjust?

Comment: I try my example with Python 2.7.5 and 3.3.2 on Linux Mint and it works - so I have no idea why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: Ok. I'm on Python 3.4.0 and running Windows 7.  There must be a change from 3.3.2 to here which is causing this, unfortunately I have no experience with that version.